# My app crashes in landscape mode

Tags: java, android, orientation, landscape

I have a problem with my Android app:

My app is a tabhost that has three columns, two normal views and a listview.
My app crashes when I change the orietation of my tablet. I tried different things, and I get a solution, but it isn't a good one.

I put this in the manifest: `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"`.
With this solution my app doesn't crash when I change the orientation, but I have two new problems, one of them is that I can't start the app in landscape mode, because if I have the tablet in horizontal mode my app crashes.

And the other problem is:
my app doesn't change the layout to landscape. When I change the orientation my app automatically put in the normal layout but in horizontal.

Here is the logcat output:

```
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.vicomtech.edonontv/org.vicomtech.edonontv.main}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.vicomtech.edonontv/org.vicomtech.edonontv.activityDatos}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.vicomtech.edonontv/org.vicomtech.edonontv.activityDatos}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2503)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:651)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at org.vicomtech.edonontv.main.onCreate(main.java:77)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     ... 11 more
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at org.vicomtech.edonontv.activityDatos.onCreate(activityDatos.java:140)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     ... 19 more
```

and the main program:

```
public class main extends TabActivity {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

     // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, activityPartido.class);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos").setIndicator("Bideoak",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_artists))
                      .setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, activityLista.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Sarea").setIndicator("Sarea",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_albums))
                      .setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, activityDatos.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Datuak").setIndicator("Datuak",
                          res.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_tab_songs))
                    .setContent(intent);

        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(2);

    }
}
```

and a part of activityDatos:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activitydatos); 
          refresh = new RefreshHandler();
          updateUI();
private String retrieveStream(String url) {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = null;
        try {
            response = client.execute(request);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.w(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.w(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String html = "";
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.w(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuilder str =null;
        try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        str = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE, e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        html = str.toString();
        return html;
```

thanks for everything

Comment: Before applying bandaids, you need to try to fix the problem. IMO you should address the original issue.
Please list the original logcat error and pertinent code.

Comment: If the app crashes on orientation change, theres something wrong with your activity lifecycle. I wouldnt 'patch' it by handling the orientation change yourself, this is almost never necessary (except perhaps in games or so), but if you do choose to, you have to reload all layout manually.

Comment: This line is the offending one:

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 09:09:56.624: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3010):     at org.vicomtech.edonontv.activityDatos.onCreate(activityDatos.java:140)

Comment: @Itzal no line numbers in your code, which one is activityDatos.java:140 ?